# jQuery selector can't find added elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selector

I know that the solution is the `jQuery.on`-function but it don't work as I expect it would do.

Following problem: 
I pull via Websocket(JSON) data and build my page up inside the document ready function (for connection reasons).
That means I add several input fields via the `jQuery.append()`-function and try to access the select-input when the SET button is pressed. Accessing the select input fails.
I have selected the body as parent element, every other form field should be in it.

For demo reasons I removed the Websocket-Functions. I have hardcoded the form as it would be in real. The debug-messages are displayed in the firebug-console.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLauohjd/

This is the way I am accessing the select input

```
$("body").on('click', ':button', function () {
    console.log( $( this ).text() ); //Value of the pressed button
    var ip = $(this).attr('ip');
    var selectvalue = "#" + "modeselect" + ip;
    console.log(selectvalue); //Print the selector to verify it is ok
    console.log($(selectvalue).val()); //fails ->not found in DOM
```

Any help on that is very appreciated!

Comment: The button has no `text()`, so that's an empty string. It also has no `ip` attribute, so that's undefined, which means `selectvalue` is `#modeselectundefined`. Nothing matches this selector.

Comment: Instead of `$(selectvalue).val()` , try: `$('body').find(selectvalue).val()`

Comment: The problem was not (as I thought) the `.on`-function. As you see in the comments-section of the selected answer the correct escaping was the solution. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a tag with jQuery, use just the tag name.

```
$("body").on('click', 'button', function () { .. } // any button clicked on body
```

As for actually retrieving the values, you won't be able to do so unless you escape the dots.

```
$("#modeselect127\\.0\\.0\\.1").val();
```

You could use something like:

```
var selectvalue = "#" + "modeselect" + ip.replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fails for me, but this `var selectvalue = "#" + "modeselect" + ip.replace(/\./g,"\\.");` works (http://jsfiddle.net/gLauohjd/2/)

Comment: @Moob: this was the solution! Thank you very much! I just was blind for the dots in the ip. I was not thinking about to escape them properly.